# Error: expected primary-expression before '>' token

Tags: c++, templates

so I was writing my code and everything was working fine. Then I had a compiler issue and had to create my project all over again and rewrite some lines of code.

Now I'm getting this error where before it did not exist, and I am getting it in multiple lines .. Can't figure out why.

(It is all happening when throwing the exceptions)

Example::

```
if (!encontrouInicio) throw NoInexistente<N>(inicio);
```

and

```
 if ((*it)->info == inf) throw NoRepetido<N>(inf);
```

Thanks in advance (y)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: So, what is `N` in these lines?

Answer (score 0):

If `N` is type variable of your class you should in the call give it a real type or something that is present there like:

```
int magicNumber = 5;
throw NoInexistente<int>(magicNumber);
```